# Ajax send javascript variable to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a JS variable to a PHP file but it does not seem to be working. In the console its showing an error as an `show.php` file. I am not able to understand What I am doing wrong.

```js
function details(id) {
  var id = id;
  //   alert(id);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'show.php',
    data: id,
    success: function(data) {
      alert("hi");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="details(<?php echo $id ; ?>)" class="btn btn-rounded btn-primary">Details</button>
```

show.php:

```php
<?php 
  if (isset($_POST['id']))
  {
    $uid = $_POST['id'];
    echo json_encode($uid);
  }
?>
```

Comment: its showing no error in console but just display show.php under console list @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: what type of error you are getting in console, can you show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your network tab and check the sending parameters list . You have to mention datatype json

Try this

```
function details(id)
    {
        var id = id;
     //   alert(id);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'show.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:  {'id':id},
            success: function(data)
            {
             alert("hi");
            }
        });
    }
```

In your show.php

```
<?php 
  if (isset($_POST['id']))
  {
    $uid = $_POST['id'];
    echo json_encode($uid);
  }
?>
```

Comment: what error you are getting ? kindly check your show.php path . is it correct?

Comment: Ok I got it the error is in directory location. both the files are in subfolders. but the `url`  fetches from the mainfolder. @WEX

Comment: yes I checked the code is fine just need to make sure file show.php file path is correct,

Comment: its showing error : Undefined variable: uid in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecgdash2\show.php on line 15

Comment: I updated my answer kindly have a look I posted the code for `show.php`  i tried at my localhost its working fine for me. Let me know if you are getting still error or show me your `show.php` file code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208492/discussion-between-wex-and-chempooro).

Comment: Remove the quotes from `'id'` in the AJAX request.

Answer (score 2):

Write data in json object
see code below

```
function details(id)
    {
        var id = id;
     //   alert(id);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'show.php',
            data:  {id:id},
            success: function(data)
            {
             alert("hi");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Remove the quotes from `'id'`